# C++ namespaces as modules?

Tags: c++

In the past, I would write classes like this:

```
// my_class.h

class MyClass
{
public:
    // Signals emitted by MyClass objects.
    typedef boost::signal<..> SignalA;
    typedef boost::signal<..> SignalB;

    enum SomeEnum
    {
        ..
    };

    enum AnotherEnum
    {
        ..
    };

    typedef some_type SomeOtherType;

    // an exception thrown by MyClass objects
    class ExceptionA
    {
        ..
    };

    MyClass();

   // rest of class definition omitted
};
```

The thing I always hated about this style is that it convoluted the class declaration.  So then for a recent project I decided to try something new.  I decided to use namespaces in a fashion similar to that of modules in Python (we also use Python a lot where I work):

```
// my_class.h

namespace my_class
{
    // Signals emitted by MyClass objects.
    typedef boost::signal<..> SignalA;
    typedef boost::signal<..> SignalB;

    enum SomeEnum
    {
        ..
    };

    enum AnotherEnum
    {
        ..
    };

    typedef some_type SomeOtherType;

    // an exception thrown by MyClass objects
    class ExceptionA
    {
        ..
    };

    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        MyClass();
        ..
    };
}
```

And the result wasn't too bad.  The only downside is that you always had to prefix "my_class::" before everything.  But that could be alleviated by utilizing "using" statements.

I am about start another project and I was thinking of doing this again.  Are there any serious downsides (other than increased verbosity) to adopting this use of namespaces?

Comment: I would say the increased verbosity is a good thing, and have stopped using the `using` statement almost completely. Still use it for deeply nested namespaces, like those in Boost. I also have lots of nested (only a couple of levels) namespaces in my projects, and almost the only code not in a namespace is the `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the name my_class, that should be fine. In fact, that is the purpose of namespaces.

Comment: Well, the reasoning behind naming it "my_class" is that it's named after the "primary" class provided by that namespace except using words-separated-by-underscores style instead of PascalCasing. This is similar to the style often used in Python where the module is named myclass (they don't like using underscores there for some reason) and class offered by myclass.py is named MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how you should do it.  One thing to keep in mind is that you want to avoid circular dependencies between namespaces. Furthermore, IMHO it is a good idea for each namespace to correspond to a separate library. That also implies that you should avoid nesting the namespaces too deeply.  Maybe one top level namespace for your company to differentiate from third party code, and then another level of namespaces for individual components.

Comment: When I first started using namespaces, I tried the idea of having everything wrapped under a namespace named after the product.  This turned out to be a pain later on when I wanted to use a component of that product in another product.  It was either keep the namespace named after the old product (looks awkward and possibly confusing) or do a search-and-replace to change the product name to that of the new product (could introduce errors).  Wrapping everything under a namespace named after the company I work for is reasonable though, since this is least likely to change from project to project